# Mongo - Is finding by _id alone (findById) faster than finding using _id and an indexed field to utilise an index?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I have a curious question and cannot seem to find an answer.

I am querying a single document and know its _id. Until now I have assumed findById is the best to approach.

However, I am wondering If I know this document sits within an index which would narrow it's down greatly. Would I better search using _id and some other field which has a specific index

Examples - I know its "_id" but I also know it's "season" and we have the collection indexed by season

The assumed approach

```
Model.findById().lean();
```

My curious approach may be better ? Faster?

```
Model.findOne({ season: "", _id: "" }).lean();
```

What I am wondering is will the season index help me find it faster than an entire search using only _id

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

### Technically not.

MongoDB uses [B-tree](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes) indexes.

B-tree properties:

```
Algorithm   Average     Worst case
Space       O(n)        O(n)
Search      O(log n)    O(log n)
Insert      O(log n)    O(log n)
Delete      O(log n)    O(log n)
```

[image: Index searching]

As soon as data grows, it takes the same time to findout as average.

Even if you create `Compound Index` consists of `{ season: 1, _id: 1 }`, the index sorts first by `season` and then, within each season value, sorts by `_id`.

Comment: You say "the index sorts by season" first. I thought the index was already sorted? So example when searching the index for "season", your actually only searching a small array like so ["2018", "2019", "2020"]. When you find your season, that then has nested all the specific season pointers. ??
So your saying in this case findById will be faster ?
Also, I will read and understand what B-Tree is. I probably already did this tree in college but forget, but ill get back up to speed with this. Need to understand it better